# Calculation to get page count based on # of items

Tags: python, math

If I have 177 items, and each page has 10 items that means I'll have 18 pages.

I'm new to python and having used any of the math related functions.

How can I calculate 177/10 and then get round up so I get 18 and not 17.7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import math
math.ceil(float(177)/10)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with integer arithmetic:

```
items_per_page = 10
number_of_pages = (x + items_per_page - 1) // items_per_page
```